# set comprehension syntax error using numpy

Tags: python, numpy, set

I'm trying to pick random zone in an image using numpy.

I'm using a python set to ensure that all my zones are unique, however, later when trying to generate a mask from this set, I'm getting an "SyntaxError: invalid syntax"

here is the code I'm using:

```
def _get_positions(self):
    small_shape = int(self._width / MACROPIXEL_SIZE)
    small_mask = numpy.zeros((small_shape, small_shape), dtype=numpy.uint8)
    #how many macropixel we will pick
    nb_pick = int((small_shape * small_shape) * self._alter_percentage)

    position_set = set()
    #try again until we pick 'nb_pick' unique positions
    while len(position_set) < nb_pick:
        pick = numpy.random.choice(small_shape, 2)
        position_set.add((pick[0], pick[1]))

    # mark the selected pixels
    {small_mask[pos_x][pos_y]=1 for (pos_x, pos_y) in position_set}
    # full size mask
    self.mask = numpy.kron(small_mask, numpy.ones(self._height, self._width))
```

code explanation:

- I need to process a lot of images, so I'm trying to optimize my code
- I'm trying to pick random zones using a simpler version of this image (this is the 'small shape' and 'small mask').
- when the set is full of unique positions, I'm using it to mark on the mask which part of the image where selected
- and at last, I'm rescaling the mask

why the set comprehension give a syntax error ? what am I doing wrong ?

--edit--
error trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_random_alteration.py", line 27, in <module>
    import alter_labels
  File "/home/abgrall/segmentation/loreal/histo_erp_fm/alter_labels.py", line 56
    {small_mask[pos_x][pos_y]=1 for (pos_x, pos_y) in position_set}
                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Can you post the error trace, please?

Comment: edited the post

Comment: The use of an assignment `=` in a set comprehension is invalid.  In it is wrong in any comprehension.  An equality test is ok  `a==1`.  Comprehensions should not be used for side-effects.  The purpose of a `set comprehension` is to collect a unique set of values, and return a `set` object.  You may need to reread the documentation for Python `set`.

Comment: Since `small_mask` is a 2d array, it can be indexed with: `small_mask[pos_x, pos_y]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not the [`set comprehension`](http://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/comprehensions/set_comprehension.html) that you are using here

```
{small_mask[pos_x][pos_y]=1 for (pos_x, pos_y) in position_set}
```

these comprehensions are for creating sets of objects. You are using it to assign a value to an array - which is invalid syntax.

Instead,

```
for pos_x, pos_y in position_set:
    small_mask[pos_x][pos_y] = 1
```

However, if you are trying to make this more efficient, you can complitly vectorize your random selection of the `pos_x, pos_y` pairs and vectorize the access on `small_mask`.

```
def _get_positions(self):
    small_shape = int(self._width / MACROPIXEL_SIZE)
    small_mask = numpy.zeros((small_shape, small_shape), dtype=numpy.uint8)
    #how many macropixel we will pick
    nb_pick = int((small_shape * small_shape) * self._alter_percentage)

    nx, ny = small_shape, small_shape
    xy = np.mgrid[:nx,:ny].reshape(2, -1).T
    pos = xy.take(np.random.choice(xy.shape[0], nb_pick, replace=False), axis=0)

    small_mask[pos] = 1 
    self.mask = numpy.kron(small_mask, numpy.ones(self._height, self._width))
```

Comment: Is it possible to have a little bit more explanation ? why I couldn't use a comprehension ?

Comment: You can not use it because you are trying to assign values to an array instead of creating a set. @MelAbgrall.

Comment: Comprehensions in Python construct objects, not modify them

Comment: thanks for the edit and the answer ! I'll look into it !